# ruamel.yaml how to use roundtripdumper

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to dump the yaml string with single quotes,

```
yaml_str = """\
dic:
  - A: var1    # need to get these strings quoted
  - B: var2
  - C: var3
  - D: var4
  - E: 3       # leave this alone
```

I found this link where it can be done using RoundTripDumper
[Force quotes in yaml.dump Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947653/force-quotes-in-yaml-dump-python)

```
dd = yaml.RoundTripDumper
dd.process_scalar = process_scalar
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, Dumper=dd)
```

But it seems the new version of raume.yml doesn't support this function.
Can someone comment on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer i need to use

```
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
```